blazor scheme already exists : addidentities
As you can see in the screenshot, I have only one place where i add identity. I made a custom user manager and registered it.
I don't know how to get any other possible duplicate, and it says it's already added
enter image description here
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Authorization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Swamp.Components;
using Swamp.Components.Account;
using Swamp.Data;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddRazorComponents()
    .AddInteractiveServerComponents();

builder.Services.AddCascadingAuthenticationState();
builder.Services.AddScoped<IdentityUserAccessor>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<IdentityRedirectManager>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<AuthenticationStateProvider, IdentityRevalidatingAuthenticationStateProvider>();
var connectionString = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection") ?? throw new InvalidOperationException("Connection string 'DefaultConnection' not found.");

builder.Services.AddDbContextFactory<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
    options.UseSqlServer(connectionString));

builder.Services.AddQuickGridEntityFrameworkAdapter(); ;

builder.Services.AddAuthentication(options =>
    {
        options.DefaultScheme = IdentityConstants.ApplicationScheme;
        options.DefaultSignInScheme = IdentityConstants.ExternalScheme;
    })
    .AddIdentityCookies();

builder.Services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
    options.UseSqlServer(connectionString));

builder.Services.AddQuickGridEntityFrameworkAdapter();
builder.Services.AddDatabaseDeveloperPageExceptionFilter();

builder.Services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>()
    .AddUserManager<UserManagerExtension>()
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
    .AddSignInManager()
    .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
builder.Services.AddServerSideBlazor().AddCircuitOptions(x => x.DetailedErrors = true);

builder.Services.AddSingleton<IEmailSender<ApplicationUser>, IdentityNoOpEmailSender>();
var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseMigrationsEndPoint();
}
else
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error", createScopeForErrors: true);
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    app.UseHsts();
    app.UseMigrationsEndPoint();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseAntiforgery();


app.MapRazorComponents<App>()
    .AddInteractiveServerRenderMode();

// Add additional endpoints required by the Identity /Account Razor components.
app.MapAdditionalIdentityEndpoints();

app.Run();


I searched for any other place with Services.AddIdentities, nothing comes up

When use AddIdentity, this will implicitly add a cookie which has the scheme name "Identity.Application".
But you use another .AddIdentityCookies(); which is basically the same sheme name cookie. This is not neccessary.
